# How can I dispose ChangeNotifierProvider<T>.value( ) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dispose, provider

how can I dispose ChangeNotifierProvider.value( ) in Flutter

so there will be no memory leaks

I made the object that is as a value to the ChangeNotifierProvider.value( ) as a singleton
cause I need more than page to share their state in one object

Answer (score 3):

`ChangeNotifierProvider` automatically calls the `dispose()` method of the state when it is needed. You need not do anything about that. They talk about this in this video:[Pragmatic State Management in Flutter (Google I/O'19)](https://youtu.be/d_m5csmrf7I?t=1345)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `dispose()` method of `State` or the default constructor of `ChangeNotifierProvider`. The latter automatically disposes of the object created in the `create` function.

I wonder why you are using `ChangeNotifierProvider.value()` instead of `ChangeNotifierProvider()`, but assuming you want to pass the value to a different page, you can combine both as follows.

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<Foo>(
  create: (context) => Foo(),  // this Foo object is disposed of automatically
)
```

Somewhere down the tree:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute<void>(
    builder: (context2) => Provider<Foo>.value(
      value: Provider.of<Foo>(context, listen: false),
      child: NextPage(),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Note: You won't have to do this if you provide the value from above `MaterialApp`.

Comment: it didn't work, I have three pages and the second and the third page at some point require to use the state of the first one, in other words, the following 2 pages depend on the state of the first one so how they can access the state of the first one while the providers at all are not at the top of the MaterialApp ??

Comment: @Karrar What you call "the state of the first page" is not actually the state only specific to that page. In such a case, it is better to place `ChangeNotifierProvider` above `MaterialApp` to enable the state given from there to be accessible across routes from anywhere in the same tree.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are only correct for `ChangeNotifierProvider` default constructor but not for `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` named constructor which is the one in the question.

According to the package author, you are responsible for disposing the object:

> ChangeNotifierProvider.value will not dispose the ChangeNotifier
>
> It is your job to do so (with a typical StatefulWidget?), as using the `.value` constructor, it is impossible for provider to know if the object is no longer used.
>
> *From: the following Github Issue Comment: [How to dispose a ChangeNotifier which is also provided with a ChangeNotifierProvider.value?](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/426#issuecomment-624743502)*